# Octave Psychtoolbox crashing when the screen is called to be displayed

Tags: octave, psychtoolbox

I am still new in Octave with some experience in Python and I was requested to do a test in a stimulus application in order to find if there are errors in the code (not developed by me) and try to fix them and run the application. The issue in the code is at the time to open the screen as follows the implementation (these ones where I commented (%) are what already did before, and these ones below the comments are my correction) the code is large with 825 lines:

```
%% Get subject name from the user

prompt = {'Enter Subject Number:','Enter Subject Name:','Enter Todays Date:','Left or Right:'};
dlgtitle = 'Information Input';
%dims = [1 50];
dims = [1 50;1 50;1 50;1 50];
opts = 'on';
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlgtitle,dims);
%waitfor(answer);
waitfor(dims);

%% TO Excel 

% Get the name of the file that the user wants to save.
%startingFolder = userpath;
startingFolder = 'C:\Users\Vtr\Downloads\Final-task-981203\Final-task-981203\Task-981203';
defaultFileName = fullfile(startingFolder, '*.xlsx');
[baseFileName, folder] = uiputfile(defaultFileName, 'Specify a filename ');
if baseFileName == 0
    % User clicked the Cancel button.
    return;
end
% Combine the folder and base file name into the full file name.
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);

%% LOAD text initial setting

%% Create 1st screen : (Loading and Wait)text screen

% Open an on screen window - purple screen
[window, windowRect] = PsychImaging('OpenWindow', screenNumber, [0.5 0.5 1]);
% Set up alpha-blending for smooth (anti-aliased) lines
Screen('BlendFunction', window, 'GL_SRC_ALPHA', 'GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA');
```

After that, in the first part is created a form to insert subject nº, subject name, today's date and left or right, and after that to specify a filename. Made these two parts it appears a purple screen with the mouse's cursor rotating non-stop and if I try to click with the mouse an error alert box "octave-gui.exe has stopped working" appears on. I already tried to run this code on my Virtualbox-VM (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), firstly, it notifies that my screen is being tested and calibrated and after, it appears another error screen on the terminal:

```
PTB-INFO: OS support status: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic Supported.
PTB-INFO: Type 'PsychtoolboxVersion' for more detailed version information.
PTB-INFO: Most parts of the Psychtoolbox distribution are licensed to you under terms of the MIT License, with
PTB-INFO: some restrictions. See file 'License.txt' in the Psychtoolbox root folder for the exact licensing conditions.


PTB-WARNING: FAILED to enable synchronization to vertical retrace!


PTB-WARNING: FAILED to enable synchronization to vertical retrace (System ignored setting [Req 1 != Actual 0])!

PTB-INFO: Failed to enable realtime-scheduling [Operation not permitted]!
PTB-INFO: You need to run Matlab or Octave with root-privileges, or run the script PsychLinuxConfiguration once for this to work.
PTB-INFO: See /usr/share/doc/psychtoolbox-3-common/README.Debian to make this work.
PTB-WARNING: Couldn't even collect one single valid flip interval sample! Sanity range checks failed!
PTB-WARNING: Could be a system bug or a temporary timing problem. Retrying the procedure might help if
PTB-WARNING: the latter is the culprit.

WARNING: VBL Calibration run No. 1 failed. Retrying...
PTB-INFO: Failed to enable realtime-scheduling [Operation not permitted]!
PTB-INFO: You need to run Matlab or Octave with root-privileges, or run the script PsychLinuxConfiguration once for this to work.
PTB-INFO: See /usr/share/doc/psychtoolbox-3-common/README.Debian to make this work.
PTB-WARNING: Couldn't even collect one single valid flip interval sample! Sanity range checks failed!
PTB-WARNING: Could be a system bug or a temporary timing problem. Retrying the procedure might help if
PTB-WARNING: the latter is the culprit.

WARNING: VBL Calibration run No. 2 failed. Retrying...
WARNING: Will enable VBL busy wait-workaround before trying final VBL Calibration run No. 3.
WARNING: This will hopefully work-around graphics driver bugs of the GPU sync-to-retrace mechanism. Cross your fingers!
PTB-INFO: Failed to enable realtime-scheduling [Operation not permitted]!
PTB-INFO: You need to run Matlab or Octave with root-privileges, or run the script PsychLinuxConfiguration once for this to work.
PTB-INFO: See /usr/share/doc/psychtoolbox-3-common/README.Debian to make this work.
PTB-WARNING: Couldn't even collect one single valid flip interval sample! Sanity range checks failed!
PTB-WARNING: Could be a system bug or a temporary timing problem. Retrying the procedure might help if
PTB-WARNING: the latter is the culprit.


PTB-INFO: OpenGL-Renderer is VMware, Inc. :: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM; :: 2.1 Mesa 18.0.5
PTB-INFO: VBL startline = 664 , VBL Endline = -1
PTB-INFO: Beamposition queries unsupported or defective on this system. Using basic timestamping as fallback.
PTB-INFO: Timestamps returned by Screen('Flip') will be therefore less robust and accurate.
PTB-INFO: Measured monitor refresh interval from VBLsync = 0.000000 ms [inf Hz]. (0 valid samples taken, stddev=10000000.000000 ms.)
PTB-INFO: Reported monitor refresh interval from operating system = 16.667222 ms [59.998001 Hz].
PTB-INFO: Small deviations between reported values are normal and no reason to worry.

WARNING: Couldn't compute a reliable estimate of monitor refresh interval! The trouble with VBL syncing?!?

WARNING: Mismatch between measured monitor refresh interval and interval reported by the operating system.
This indicates massive problems with VBL sync.


----- ! PTB - ERROR: SYNCHRONIZATION FAILURE ! -----

One or more internal checks (see Warnings above) indicate that synchronization
of Psychtoolbox to the vertical retrace (VBL) is not working on your setup.

This will seriously impair proper stimulus presentation and stimulus presentation timing!
Please read 'help SyncTrouble' for information about how to solve or work-around the problem.
You can force Psychtoolbox to continue, despite the severe problems, by adding the command
Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 1); at the top of your script, if you really know what you are doing.

error: Screen: See error message printed above.
error: Called from
    PsychImaging at line 2240 column 26
    Naderi_test_task_v_main_1203_v_2 at line 110 column 20
```

I would like to know if the issue is in my computer configurations that don't support Psychtoolbox resources or any configuration that I need to change.

Comment: Silly question, but apparently the psychtoolbox project offers different downloads for octave and matlab. Are you _sure_ you are using the _octave_ version of the psychtoolbox?

Comment: Also, the line `PTB-INFO: You need to run Matlab or Octave with root-privileges, or run the script PsychLinuxConfiguration once for this to work.` ... have you done this?

Comment: Hi there @TasosPapastylianou, yes, for that I figure I am using the Octave version of the psychtoolbox... when I type at the command line in Octave GUI/CLI it shows: 
` >> PsychtoolboxVersion
ans = 3.0.16 - Flavor: beta - Corresponds to SVN Revision 10420
For more info visit:
https://github.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3
 `

Comment: `PTB-INFO: See /usr/share/doc/psychtoolbox-3-common/README.Debian to make this work.` what does this file suggest?  ( are you even ON linux? your code seems to suggest windows filenames ... )